# Checking if an element is in the array or not infinite loop

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to see if a number is in the array or not in logn time but this function executes

```
else if(arr[(r-l)/2] < n)
```

all the time and it becomes an infinite loop. Why is that?

```
int exists(int n, int *arr, int l, int r){
    if(l == r){

        if(arr[l] == n){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else if(arr[(r-l)/2] == n){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(arr[(r-l)/2] > n){
        return exists(n, arr, l, (r-l)/2);
    }
    else if(arr[(r-l)/2] < n){
        return exists(n, arr, (r-l)/2, r);
    }
}

int main(){
    node *root = NULL;

    int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%d", exists(5, arr, 0, 4));

}
```

Comment: please provide complete code, including the call to exists() as well as sample input and expected output

Comment: You haven't posted any loop.  You aren't going to get any actual answers until you do.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's a recursive implementation of a binary search (sigh!) (i.e.) it doesn't need a loop.

Comment: If `l` is 6 and `r` is 10, what is `(r-l)/2` ?

Comment: @CraigEstey *It's a recursive implementation of a binbary search (sigh!) (i.e.) it doesn't need a loop.* You didn't look at the edit history, did you?

Comment: I think I should've used arr[((r-l)/2)+l] the whole time

Comment: or simply (l + r) / 2....see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

well, if

```
else if (arr[(r-l)/2] == n) {
```

is being executed, then it is because

```
if (l == r) {
```

is false

It looks like you are trying to do a binary search, if so, your index computations are all wrong.

```
int exists(int n, int *arr, int l, int r) {
    if (l <= r) {
        int mid = (l + r) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] == n) {
            return 1;
        } else if (arr[mid] > n) {
            return exists(n, arr, l, mid - 1);
        } else {
            return exists(n, arr, mid + 1, r);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is what happens when you try to implement binary search without actually learning it... Thank you I'll change my code and come back

Comment: No problem, look at the code, try to understand what it does, and feel free to ask about it...a great way to learn these types of algorithms.  The only thing tricky about it might be the first condition `if (l <= r)` which is really just checking for our ending condition, in which we have moved left and right so much, they have crossed each other.

Comment: It works!! I completely understood the algorithm and tested the code! I love you and thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome, glad to have helped....now figure out how to do it non-recursively.  It's very similar, just use a loop instead of recursive calls, and manipulate `l` and `r` depending on the value of the `mid` element you are examining.